# Setting the Date on the wx.calendar CalendarCtrl Widget

Tags: python, calendar, wxpython, calendar-control

I'm trying to set the selected date so that it is always the current day. How would I go about this?

Currently if I let the widget sit for more than a day, the selected date doesn't update. Thus the date would be behind. How would I go about changing the selected date, so that it's always up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set a timer (`wx.Timer`) instance to produce a `wx.EVT_TIMER` every several few seconds/minutes and bind the event to a method in charge of updating the calendar with the current date (`wx.DateTime_Now()`) if required.

Here you have a minimal working demo code (try to change the date: it will go back to the current date after a second):

```
import  wx
import  wx.calendar

class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.cal = wx.calendar.CalendarCtrl(self, -1, wx.DateTime_Now())
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update_date)

    def update_date(self, evt):
        date = wx.DateTime_Now()
        self.cal.SetDate(date)    

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyCalendar(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```